# flutter: Can't open specific page from pdf file

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I tried to open specific page using ['advanced pdf viewer'](https://pub.dev/packages/advance_pdf_viewer) library, but it doesn't work. Is here any mistake or it's just an invalid library function?

my code:

```
import 'package:advance_pdf_viewer/advance_pdf_viewer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GuidePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GuidePageState createState() => _GuidePageState();
}

class _GuidePageState extends State<GuidePage> {

  bool _isLoading = true;
  PDFDocument document;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadDocument();
    openPage(3);
  }

  loadDocument() async {
    document = await PDFDocument.fromAsset('assets/guide_rus_small.pdf');
    setState(() => _isLoading = false);
  }

  void openPage(_number) async {
    PDFPage page = await document.get(page: _number);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: _isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : PDFViewer(
            document: document,
            showNavigation: true,
            zoomSteps: 1,
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Maybe you know a better solution to do this task

Comment: any error thrown or just blank?

Comment: When opening a page, the first page is displayed